# Rescanning of LUN process in Redhat Linux

Tags: rhel, storage

I use the below syntax to find newly added LUN from server end. I just wanted to know the exact meaning/ process of "- - -". Can anyone explain me about that?

echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host1/scan

Thanks,
Athiri

Answer (score 0):

From [RedHat Online Starage Reconfiguration Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Online_Storage_Reconfiguration_Guide/adding_storage-device-or-path.html):

```
echo "c t l" > /sys/class/scsi_host/hosth/scan
```

> h is the HBA number, c is the channel on the HBA, t is the SCSI target
>   ID, and l is the LUN

- is a wildcard sign in that case.

Comment: No problem. If I helped, upvote and mark as as answered, please :)

Comment: Can you tell me to vote. I am not sure about the process.

Comment: [StackExchange Tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)